# Run Dynamic Code in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, dynamic

I'm sure most (if not all) of you know what Batch scripts are, (.bat files) I've been wondering lately, if you can run dynamic code? Like say you wanted to run a line of code imputed by the user? I'd like to be able to do this without external files.

I tried researching this but didn't find anything. Is it possible? How can you do it?

Comment: Sure, save it to a new temporary .bat file and `call` it.

Comment: @blorge can you without external files by any chance?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:top
set /p usercmd=Enter command line
%usercmd%
goto top
```

Batch files are read 1 line at a time, closed, line executed, file reopened and read again. Nothing stops you editing the file.

Comment: So just saying %usercmd% will work? It's so simple, why didn't I find it on the Internet?

Comment: If so simple why didn't you try it before commenting? It has limitations, esp trying to use variables in your command.

Comment: I'm on mobile atm, can't accept until I test it. Is there anyway to get around those limitations?

Comment: Not without a temporary file, which you've already indicated is unacceptable for what you need. The main reason you can't find anything about this online is that not only is it super dangerous since there's not really any good way to error check, but it's essentially the batch version of SQL injection.

Comment: Maybe if the user escapes the percent sign with either % or ^. If your problem is Group Policy No Interactive Command Prompt, just issues the commands from Start - Run, Winkey + R (`cmd /c dir & pause`)